# How do I make database of files and folders existing on an external hard drive?

Tags: files, directory

I have an external 1 TB hard drive with lots of media files (contained singly or in different folders), books, software etc. I would like to create a database file, maybe a spreadsheet file, which can show me a list of the files existing in the external drive. I would like to search through that file and find the media I was looking for even when the hard drive was not connected to the system.

In Windows 10 I use Easy Disk Catalog Maker for the job but I cannot find a similar software for Linux. So how do I go about it?

Comment: `find /PATH/TO/EXTERNAL/HDD/ -type f -follow > "/PATH/TO/SAVE/file_list.txt"` This should create a searchable text file of all the files on the external HDD with their paths included. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a list of files, you can use a simple `find`, like @Raffa commented.

```
find /PATH/TO/EXTERNAL/HDD/ -type f -follow > "/PATH/TO/SAVE/file_list.txt"
```

---

If you want to save metadata information of your multimedia files, you can use `mediainfo`, that reads information for audio, video and picture files:

```
find /PATH/TO/EXTERNAL/HDD/ -type f -follow \
  -exec mediainfo -f --Output=XML + > "/PATH/TO/SAVE/file_list.xml"
```

You can then read the output with any regular xml parser, e.g. `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/Mediainfo/File/track/Complete_name' -n "/PATH/TO/SAVE/file_list.xml"
```

or e.g. search only images:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
  -v '/Mediainfo/File/track[@type="Image"]/../track/Complete_name' \
  -n \
  "/PATH/TO/SAVE/file_list.xml"
```

or find all images with file size > 1MB:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
  -v '/Mediainfo/File/track[@type="Image"]/../track[@type="General"][File_size[1] > 1048576]/Complete_name' \
  -n \
  "/PATH/TO/SAVE/file_list.xml"
```

---

Installation:

```
sudo apt install mediainfo
sudo apt install xmlstarlet
```

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual Volumes View](http://vvvapp.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a GUI open source and free solution:

> VVV is an application that catalogs the content of removable volumes
> like CD and DVD disks for off-line searching. Folders and files can
> also be arranged in a single, virtual file system. Each folder of this
> virtual file system can contain files from many disks so you can
> arrange your data in a simple and logical way.
>
> VVV also stores metadata information from audio files: author, title,
> album and so on. Most audio formats are supported.

- [Download](http://vvvapp.sourceforge.net/download.html) the Linux version.
- Extract the downloaded `VVV-*.tar.gz` file.
- In the terminal `cd` to the extracted directory then run `bash vvv-start.sh`

---

**To add a launcher for VVV on your desktop:**

Run in the terminal:

```
nano ~/Desktop/vvvapp.desktop
```

Copy and paste this into the editor changing `/FULL/PATH/TO/vvv-start.sh` to reflect the full path to `vvv-start.sh` on your system:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/FULL/PATH/TO/vvv-start.sh
Name=Virtual Volumes View
```

Close the editor and save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> then make the file executable by running:

```
chmod u+x ~/Desktop/vvvapp.desktop
```

Comment: I get this error:

surja:VVV-1.3.0-i386$ bash vvv-start.sh 
./vvv: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @surya_hs You downloaded the file for 32-bit systems. You need [the 64-bit file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vvvapp/files/VVV/1.4/VVV-1.4.0-x86_64.tar.gz/download) instead. Your system as it looks is **64-bi**t and not 32-bit.