# How to search in Linux from the terminal, on an external HDD, for photos, by name

Tags: command-line, search

OS: Lubuntu.

Can someone please, help, which is the command from the terminal(cmd) to search on all the external HDD, on all its folders and sub-folders. I would like to search for all the photos having this inside of their names: "202010"

Are there two/three different commands if some of the photos could have in there name some characters in front of "202010" and other photos could have some characters after "202010", or maybe both ways, characters in front and after "202010" ?

Is there any update command, from the terminal, for updating the last photos copied on the external HDD, from another machine, then the machine where I actually connect the external HDD, and search for photos? Or the photos will be indexed anyway by the new machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make database of files and folders existing on an external hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310025/how-do-i-make-database-of-files-and-folders-existing-on-an-external-hard-drive)

Comment: You didn't provide release details, but `find` is the default GNU/Linux tool and is available on all releases. There are other *faster* options available that rely on databases (of your files), but you may need to install them as we don't know your release and those extra tools vary on release as to which if any are pre-installed.

Answer (score 3):

The brute force to perform this is to use the find standard command.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)

```
find <base directory> -name '202010*.jpg'
```

The quotes around the file pattern ensure that it is not matched against the file in your current directory, and transmitted as a pattern to find.
The pattern is your way to express if you want

- exactly `202010.jpg`: `-name '202010.jpg'`
- anything starting with `202010`: `-name '202010*.jpg'`
- anything containing `202010`: `-name '*202010*.jpg'`

This will get you going, but using find massively, especially `find / <whatever query>` is a bad practice and is slow, you can do better.
In most of the cases, Linux comes installed with a system called locate, or mlocate (Ubuntu, see https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-locate-command/ ).

By using another process that scans the disk regularly (once a day), locate builds a database that makes the search for something like
locate '202010*.jpg'
very efficient (seconds instead of minutes).

Comment: Just to add to this answer...  The command corresponding command to `locate` is `updatedb`.  And you can create an index for a specific file system.  This example is in the man pages:  `updatedb -l 0 -o db_file -U source_directory`.  This might come in handy since `locate` (and `mlocate`) may not index external drives by default...so you might have to force it.

Answer (score 2):

For me the easiest way to search is by console, and easy ones for me are these.

```
$ find /path -name '*202010*'
```

or

```
$ find /path | grep 202010
```